# deploy Angular/Asp.Net Core 2.1 app to AWS: 500 error

Tags: c#, angular, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core

I can host my application locally and it works fine. I can publish to Elastic Beanstalk via AWS's VS wizard without issues. But when I try to access the application, I get a 500 error and nothing loads. Everything I've found references moving files from ClientApp/dist to wwwroot, but two things...

  1. I don't have a dist folder?
  2. the last line in `public IConfiguration Configuration` sets the root path for spa static files as dist

(forgive me, this is my first angular app deployment.)

#### Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(x => x
            .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), b =>
                b.MigrationsAssembly(("MyApp.App")))
            .ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.Ignore(CoreEventId.IncludeIgnoredWarning)));

        services.AddMvc()
            .AddJsonOptions(opt =>
            {
                opt.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            })
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration => { configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist"; });

        services.AddTransient<Seed>();

        services.AddCors();

        services.AddAutoMapper();

        services.AddScoped<IAuthRepository, AuthRepository>();

        services.AddScoped<IBaseRepository, BaseRepository>();

        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value);

        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });

        services.AddScoped<LogUserActivity>();

        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.UseAuthentication();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler(builder =>
            {
                builder.Run(async context =>
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

                    var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                    if (error != null)
                    {
                        context.Response.AddApplicationError(error.Error.Message);
                        await context.Response.WriteAsync(error.Error.Message);
                    }
                });
            });
        }

        app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin().AllowCredentials());
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.ConfigureSwagger(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: 500 means unhandled exception. Try to comment out that `UseExceptionHandler` and leave the call to `UseDeveloperExceptionPage` so you can see the actual exception message.

Comment: I still just get a 500 error in the browser console. The browser window reads "An error occurred while starting the application."

Comment: I'd suggest to check the logs to get some more info. I have never used beanstalk, but I think it' explained here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html

Comment: @ChristophLütjen, after looking through the log file, I don't see anything that stands out. It shows that the deployment and build were successful. It does not, however, mention anything about my requests to the server. (I would expect that it would at least note that I made a request.)

Comment: After re-arranging a few things and commenting out add-ons, I'm getting this error: `InvalidOperationException: The SPA default page middleware could not return the default page '/index.html' because it was not found, and no other middleware handled the request.`

Comment: The `dist` directory is created as part of the Angular build process. You'll find it specified in the `<projectRoot>/ClientApp/.angular-cli.json` file generated by the ASP.NET Core 2.1 Angular template. I recognize you mentioned that it works when hosted locally, but make sure to test a deployment using `dotnet publish` to a directory and then `dotnet <dllName>` from that directory. You'll likely get more information.

Comment: Seems, that your angular app was not build correctly or was build at a wrong place. I guess "it runs locally" means "in development mode" so publish and start locally would be the way to go (as @Gnosian wrote). A common problem with angular is, that angular compiles more strictly for production. I'd suggest to compile your angular project with --prod flag for testing.

Comment: When I publish locally, I get an error that it cannot find the spa default page index.html. however, index.html definitely exists in the proper directory

Comment: I spent an entire day on this issue, and ended up recreating the whole project. I found someone else that was having a similar issue and they were able to solve it by creating the app via CLI command `dotnet new angular` rather than via Visual Studio. I did the same, and copied all of my files to the new project - and it published fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to circumvent this issue by creating a new project via the command line instead of using "File > New Project" in Visual Studio.

I created the new project with the command `dotnet new angular`

Then I copied all of the code from my old project to the new one. The new project published fine.