# Any Suggestions for getting ASP.NET Core + React Running on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core

I'm trying to get an ASP.NET Core with ReactJS application deployed to Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk. I've been using [this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/dotnet-linux-core-tutorial.html#dotnet-linux-core-tutorial-generate) to help me get started. I can deploy the tutorial (using the `dotnet new web` template) project just fine. However, when I publish a ASP.NET Core + React project (using `dotnet new react` template), I get the following exception when trying to access the application:

```
InvalidOperationException: The SPA default page middleware could not return the default page '/index.html' because it was not found, and no other middleware handled the request.
Your application is running in Production mode, so make sure it has been published, or that you have built your SPA manually. Alternatively you may wish to switch to the Development environment.
```

- This only occurs when I try to access `ClientApp/` React components. When I access an API endpoint, there is no problem.
- Additionally, this does not occur when running locally. Running locally works fine.

To reproduce this error, I've executed the following:

```sh
dotnet new react -o test-react/
dotnet publish test-react/ -o site/
cd site/
zip ../deploy.zip *
```

Finally, I manually import `deploy.zip` into AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

This is the `Startup.cs` file for that project.

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

For reference, I am targeting .NET Core 3.1. Any ideas on how to solve this problem? I believe I've tried everything suggested on [this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5223) GitHub issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This question seems similar but is obviously for Angular and not React:
[deploy Angular/Asp.Net Core 2.1 app to AWS: 500 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51616911/deploy-angular-asp-net-core-2-1-app-to-aws-500-error)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that my `deploy.zip` package wasn't being created recursively so files in subdirectories were missing. Instead of doing,

```sh
zip ../deploy.zip *
```

I did,

```sh
zip -r ../deploy.zip *
```

which worked as intended. Silly me.